# Is there a way to "intelligently" link object files from diferent languages into a final executable?

Tags: c++, c, linker, fortran

Hello (I feel like this question doesn't really make sense, so if it doesn't, let me know and I'll try and clarify).

I've been at this for a while, so I figured I'd reach out for help. Let's say I have three source files (the actual source code doesn't matter): `main.cpp` (C++), `log.c` (C), `math.f90` (Fortran).
Then, I compile them into object files:

```sh
g++ -c -o main.o main.cpp
gcc -c -o log.o log.c
gfortran -c -o math.o main.f90
```

What is the best way to link these object files together "intelligently"? By intelligently I mean linking the object files together with flags that would normally be passed if the linker was being called by the compiler (e.g. the compiler passes -lc++ when calling the linker).

For example, if I was compiling `main.cpp` into a binary in one command (`g++ main.cpp`) then it calls the linker like this:
`"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ld" -demangle -lto_library /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/libLTO.dylib -no_deduplicate -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.14.0 -syslibroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -o a.out /var/folders/lp/dhft80p975dd8k_60h616xmh0000gn/T/test-c9d010.o -L/usr/local/lib -lc++ -lSystem /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/11.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.osx.a`. If I was to do that with the C code and the Fortran code, it would call the linker differently.

I need to know how to know to compile and link these source files so that the compiler steps in and supplies some extra linker-flags.

Comment: A few things ... You're using `xcode` [macOS], so it may be different [from (e.g.) linux]. But, for GNU compilers, `gcc`, `g++`, and `gfortran` are just "front ends". (e.g.) You can compile with: `gfortran -c -x c++ main.cpp`. So, when linking, try the "dominant" front end (e.g): `g++ -o myprogram main.o log.o math.o` That would work [for sure] for `g++` and `gcc` mixed together. Try all three to see. Because they have a single common backend, they [one of them] may figure it out automatically. See what comes up missing [if any].

Comment: @CraigEstey Thanks, that's what I thought, but it seemed like it wasn't the way to go. Any tips on finding the "dominant" front-end (is it always g++)? I'm making a build system (yes, I know I'm a bad person) for education purposes, so I don't have the ability to just try each front end.

Comment: @CraigEstey also, shouldn't just using G++ to call the linker not work? Wouldn't G++ then not pass the -lgfortran flag because it's the c++ front end?

Comment: `c` will _link_ under either `g++` or `gfortran`. The latter assumes that that you've already done all the fortran vs. C declarations (e.g. in your fortran source, you've told it what extern funcs are C linkage, etc.). At most, I suspect you'll need to add an extra `-L` and/or `-lc`, etc. But, the front ends should figure this out for you. If I were doing it, I'd try `g++` and then `gfortran` and see which produces the "least pain". That is, the one with the fewest extra `-lwhatever` you need to provide. Then, once I got a clean link by hand, I'd add to my build system [as I've done before].

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying [thinking]. Just "try" it ;-) If you're wrong, all that happens is that it doesn't link. But, the diagnostic messages will give you a clue. You could also add `-v` to produce verbose messages. If you use `g++` for linking, you _might_ have to add (e.g.) `-lgfortran`, etc. If using `gfortran`, you _might_ have to add `-lg++` [or whatever].

Comment: Be aware that we have existing questions about the necessity of `-lgfortran` when linking with `gcc` or `g++` and the necessity if `-lstdc++` when linking with `gcc` or `gfortran`. The error messages you get when you leave those out can bring you there but there may should be easily searchable even without them.

Comment: Better ask yourself if there's a way to dumbly link object files, because I don't know of any.

Comment: @LuisColorado Wise words. Very wise words.